# javascript convert string to data

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have JavaScript code below.

```
var data = "[{"PR_ID":23096,"P_ID":23014},{"PR_ID":33232,"P_ID":23014},{"PR_ID":33308,"P_ID":23014},{"PR_ID":33309,"P_ID":23014}]";
```

I need convert the string to an `data` by delete the `""` surrounding the array stored as `"data"` in JavaScript so after convert it suppose like below:

```
var data = [{"PR_ID":23096,"P_ID":23014},{"PR_ID":33232,"P_ID":23014},{"PR_ID":33308,"P_ID":23014},{"PR_ID":33309,"P_ID":23014}];
```

How to make the convert?

Comment: The first line is not a valid JS litteral string ... it would need mixed `"/' ` quotes

Comment: you might be looking for `eval()`. something like `data = eval(data);`

Comment: The first line is not valid JS syntax, so you can't use JS to convert what's in `data` because the code won't even run. You'd need to fix the server-side code to return something valid.

Comment: Well then please update your question to show that properly. The first line of code shown is not valid JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert a JSON object to Javascript object use:

```
var data = '[{"PR_ID":23096,"P_ID":23014},{"PR_ID":33232,"P_ID":23014},{"PR_ID":33308,"P_ID":23014},{"PR_ID":33309,"P_ID":23014}]';
JSON.parse(data);
```

But first change the double quote to single quote, otherwise the JSON object wont be a valid JSON.

After this you can walk the array in the following way:

```
var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(data);

for(var val in jsonParsed) {
   if(jsonParsed.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
      // do something with the values
   }
}
```

Comment: I need using mustache to populate it. like var rendered = Mustache.render(template, data);  even i pass in JSON.parse(data); as the data, it still not work, untill I  delete the "" surrounding the array stored as "data" in JavaScript. but how to remove "" ?

Comment: But why you are not sending in the correct format from backend?

Comment: You need to resolve the issue before you send to javascript, otherwise JS will throw you an error